# Fixing "Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys" in R

Tags: r, group-by, r-markdown

I'm trying to import and clean up a `.csv` file using R using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyboot)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(broom.mixed) 
d <- read_csv('../stickgame/human-experiments/dataFromMongo.csv') 

complete_games <- d %>%
  filter(stimulus_type == 'isLong') %>%
  group_by(gameid) %>%
  tally() %>%
  filter(n == 2) %>%
  pull(gameid)
```

However, this yields the error on using `group_by(gameid)`: `Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 4 rows: * 70, 98 * 72, 100`. Looking at the actual rows, they all seem to be distinct:

```
    iterationName  context_id                                     gameid  \
70        sample2         NaN  6867-0dc8e3af-6056-4a4c-9c9a-ad790fa83159   
72        sample2         NaN  6867-0dc8e3af-6056-4a4c-9c9a-ad790fa83159   
98        sample2         NaN  5876-f95f302b-c649-4bdc-a8eb-12dbf4b8b3aa   
100       sample2         NaN  5876-f95f302b-c649-4bdc-a8eb-12dbf4b8b3aa   

     time  trialNum  repNum  targetImg  msg  timeFromRoundStart      rt  \
70    NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN  NaN                 NaN  2807.0   
72    NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN  NaN                 NaN  3539.0   
98    NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN  NaN                 NaN     NaN   
100   NaN       NaN     NaN        NaN  NaN                 NaN     NaN   

     agent1stick  agent2stick  quizAttempts  button_pressed  response  \
70           0.1          0.7           NaN             NaN       NaN   
72           0.1          0.7           NaN             0.0       NaN   
98           0.2          0.7           NaN             NaN       NaN   
100          0.2          0.7           NaN             NaN       NaN   

    stimulus_type stimulus_contestant  trial-index  
70            NaN                 NaN          NaN  
72            NaN                 NaN          NaN  
98            NaN                 NaN          NaN  
100           NaN                 NaN          NaN
```

I tried adding the indices the `.csv` file, but this gets the same error.

Comment: Can you run your code step-by-step and see which line exactly gives an error?

Comment: It's the `group_by(gameid)` line (line 22 in the `.Rmd` file) that yields the error when I knit the file.